# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address') when trying to use 'truffle run verify'

Tags: truffle

I have successfully deployed my contracts to the goerli testnet but for some reason, I am not able to verify my contracts using "truffle-plugin-verify". I have added the following keys to the truffle config:

```
api_keys: {
    etherscan: keys.ETHERSCAN,
  },
  plugins: ["truffle-plugin-verify"],
```

And when running `truffle run verify contract_name --network goerli`

I get:

```
Verifying contracts on etherscan
   Verifying contract_name
   Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
   Failed to verify 1 contract(s): contract_name
```

This seems to be the case for any contract I try to verify (note: I replace "contract_name" with the actual contract name). I have looked in my /build/contracts folder and everything seems to be in there. What would be the reason that this happens? Like I said, the contracts compiled and deployed properly so I do not know what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the version of truffle-plugin-verify was causing it to not work. The version I originally had was ^0.6.3 but when switching to ^0.5.32 it worked.